# How to unset object and delete it from mysqli?

Tags: php, class, oop

I have 4 classes:

1) Config - Where i store data config:

```
class Config
{
    public $configuration;
    public $e;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->configuration = array();
        $this->e = NULL;
    }

    public static function opts($hostname = NULL, $username = NULL, $password = NULL, $database = NULL, $prefix = NULL, $connector = NULL)
    {
        $istance = new self();
        $array=array(
            "hostname"  => $hostname,
            "username"  => $username,
            "password"  => $password,
            "database"  => $database,
            "prefix"    => $prefix,
            "connector" => $connector
        );
        $istance->fill($array);
        return $istance;
    }
    protected function fill($array)
    {
        $this->configuration = $array;
    }
[...]
```

2) DB - Where i manage db using data from sent Config Objects:

```
class db
{
    private $connection;
    private $selectdb;
    private $lastQuery;
    private $lastQueryString;
    private $config;

    function __construct($config)
    {
     $this->config = $config->configuration;
    }

    function __destruct()
    {

    }

    public function openConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            if($this->config["connector"] == "mysql")
            {
                $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->config["hostname"], $this->config["username"], $this->config["password"]);
                $this->selectdb = mysql_select_db($this->config["database"]);
            }
            elseif($this->config["connector"] == "mysqli")
            {
                $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->config["hostname"], $this->config["username"], $this->config["password"]);
                $this->selectdb = mysqli_select_db($this->connection, $this->config["database"]);
            }
        }
        catch(exception $e)
        {
            return $e;
        }
    }

    public function closeConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            if($this->config["connector"] == "mysql")
            {
              mysql_close($this->connection);
            }
            elseif($this->config["connector"] == "mysqli")
            {
                mysqli_close($this->connection);
            }
        }
        catch(exception $e)
        {
            return $e;
        }
    }
[...]
```

3) UserService - Where I solve all dataUsers-db requests (getbyid, by querystring, etc...):

```
class userService
{
    public $mysql;
    public function __construct($mysql)
    {
        $this->mysql = $mysql;
    }
    public function getByVar($key = "id", $value)
    {
        if($this->mysql->pingServer())
        {
            $query = $this->mysql->query("select * from {users} WHERE ".$key." = ".$value."");
            $num = $this->mysql->countRows();
            if($num>1)
            {
                $return = array();
                while($result = $this->mysql->fetchAssoc())
                {
                $return[] = User::arr($result);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $result = $this->mysql->fetchAssoc();
                $return = User::arr($result);
            }
            return $return;
        }
        else
            return $this->mysql->pingServer();
    }
[...]
```

4) User - Where I store and manage the datas got by userservice (compare, etc):

```
class User
{

    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $nome;
    public $cognome;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $other;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id= NULL;
        $this->username= NULL;
        $this->nome= NULL;
        $this->cognome= NULL;
        $this->email= NULL;
        $this->password= NULL;
        $this->other= NULL;
    }

    public static function opts($id = NULL, $username = NULL, $nome = NULL, $cognome = NULL, $email = NULL, $password = NULL, $other = NULL)
    {
        $istance = new self();
        $array = array(
            "id" => $id,
            "username" => $username,
            "nome" => $nome,
            "cognome" => $cognome,
            "email" => $email,
            "password" => $password,
            "other" => $other
        );

        $istance -> fill($result);
        return $istance;
    }

    protected function fill($array)
    {
        if(is_array($array))
        {
            foreach($array as $key => $value)
            {
                if(property_exists('User', $key))
                {
                    $this->$key = $value;
                }
                else
                    $this->other[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        else $this->username = "errore";
    }
[...]
```

The question is:

How can I, using __destruct/unset from User, delete the object and send a delete Query using userService class (like getbyid request)?

Something like this:

```
$user = new User(1,"username","nome",[...]);
$user->delete();
```

OR

```
$userService = new UserService($mysql);
$user = $userService->getByID($id);
$user->delete();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't delete object from database on unset/__destruct. You are aware that all objects are destroyed at the end of script? This means that on script end every object you used is being deleted from database.

And second thing. I would delete user using userService. Let User class manages logic, while userService is caring about db stuff.

IMHO

```
$userService->delete($user)
```

makes more sense than

```
$user->delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the code, it seems you have got overimpressed by the OOP.
Unfortunately, you took it wrong.

With such an approach  you will end up with empty user database.

Just run a regular delete query in the delete() method. As simple as that.

Comment: I read that is correct let the class do only one importart job. That is incorrect let the User Class do query